# Typo3 disable active menu link

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want the active ('ACT') menu item **not** to be linked. Why is the *doNotLinkIt = 1* not working?

The complete code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/Xb9GtJLY

```
ACT < .NO
ACT = 1
ACT {
   doNotLinkIt = 1
   linkWrap = <div class="lang_active">|</div>
   }
```

Besides that, the menu is working perfectly fine and rendered as intended.

Comment: added required context in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to note it like this because the link is created by `stdWrap.typolink` probably:

```
lib.languagemenu.20.1.ACT.stdWrap.typolink >
```

In `USERDEF1` you did it already like that.